# BackBone js - How to set contentType when making AJAX Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my application - I make an AJAX call to fetch image/binary data.

Question is how to set "application/octet-stream" as content type when making fetch() from my model ?

My Model -- I cant change fetch of "BLA" defined. How to set the CONTENT TYPE through my model ?

```
define(function(require) {
  var bla= require("bla");
return BLA.Model.extend({
   __name__: 'xyz',
        url: function() {   
            console.log(this.attributes);
            return SOME_URL + this.get('someAttribute'); 
        },
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.options = options;            
            this.promise = this.fetch(options);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW: Your [`initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) method definition is wrong. It should receive the fixed list of parameters the first of which is model **attributes**

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Model.fetch` uses `Backbone.Sync` which uses `$.ajax` to request the remote server. When you calling  `Model.fetch(options)` , `options` hash will be passed to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

In your case you could just set:

```
this.promise = this.fetch({ beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            } 
});
```